# A difference between traceroute and mtr one day

Tags: monitoring

When doing mtr to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it kept showing 2 hops in Germany ?
At the same time running traceroute to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it never showed Germany.
I'm in the USA, seems odd after multiple runs it always showed the same for both ?
Any ideas for any possible reason ? besides mtr phoning home possibilities ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably was a network glitch within your ISP, bust as you mention this is kind of strange. Have you ever notice the same behavior other days or only was once